# How to call a method within another method

Tags: iphone

I placed resumeLayer and PauseLayer method definitions within the @interface and @end block in h file.

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIToolbar *toolbar;
@property (strong)AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer * timer;

- (void)resumeLayer:(CALayer *)layer;
- (void)pauseLayer:(CALayer *)layer;

@end
```

methods in m file

```
-(void)pauseLayer:(CALayer*)layer
{
  CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil];
  layer.speed = 0.0;
  layer.timeOffset = pausedTime;
}

-(void)resumeLayer:(CALayer*)layer
{
  CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [layer timeOffset];
  layer.speed = 1.0;
  layer.timeOffset = 0.0;
  layer.beginTime = 0.0;
  CFTimeInterval timeSincePause = [layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil] - pausedTime;
  layer.beginTime = timeSincePause;
 }
```

Now want to call **resumeLayer and PauseLayer method in PlayPauseAction method**

```
-(void)playpauseAction:(id)sender {

if([audioPlayer isPlaying])
{
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Play Icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [audioPlayer pause];
    [self pauseTimer];
    [self pauseLayer: CALayer];

}
else
{
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [audioPlayer play];
    [self resumeTimer];

if(isFirstTime == YES)
    {
        self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:11.0
                                                      target:self
                                                    selector:@selector(displayviewsAction:)
                                                    userInfo:nil
                                                     repeats:NO];
        isFirstTime  = NO;
    }
   } 
  }
```

Now when i call

```
[self PauseLayer:CALayer];
```

&

```
[self resumeLayer:CALayer];
```

gets message in red that `unexpected interface name CALayer expected expression`.

Anyone can please tell how to call `PauseLayer` and `resumeLayer` method in `playpauseAction` method.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Its looks like you give class as argument. But, you must give in argument the instance of the class,

Comment: As said above....  What layer do you want to pause or resume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line does not make sense:

```
[self pauseLayer:CALayer];
```

because CALayer is a class. The compiler expects you to send in an object of type CALayer.
You need to do something like:

```
//Get a reference to your UIImageView somehow
UIImageView *myImageView = [yourOtherClass getTheImageView];

[self pauseLayer:myImageView.layer]; // Pause the CALayer of the UIImageView
```

To explain why, compare with this code, lets say you have a method like this one to add a number from an NSNumber to an int "totalValue" that is stored inside a class:

```
/** Adds the number to totalValue **/
-(int)addNumber:(NSNumber)number {
    totalValue = totalValue + [number intValue]; 

    return totalValue;
}
```

The correct way to call this method would be for example:

```
// Store the value 10 into an NSNumber
NSNumber *numberToAdd = [NSNumber numberWithInt:10];
[self addNumber:numberToAdd]; // Add number 10 to totalValue
```

But this is what you are trying to do:

```
[self addNumber:NSNumber]; // WRONG, 'NSNumber' is not a value!
```

The compiler complains because CALayer is not a value, just like NSNumber is not a value. You can not do an operation like 10 + NSNumber. The code above wants an object, an instance of the class NSNumber, not a reference to the NSNumber class itself.

Comment: i have define layer of image in separate file
UIImageView* ImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 300, 235)];
ImageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:    
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"1a.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"1b.png"],
                            nil];ImageView.animationDuration = 25;[ImageView startAnimating];ImageView.layer.borderWidth = 2;[ImageView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];[baseView addSubview:ImageView]; and play pause action method is in another file but it is loading that file

Comment: Yes, ok, but in the code you posted above it says [self pauseLayer:CALayer] not [self pauseLayer:myLayer]. That is why you get the message "unexpected interface name CALayer expected expression", because CALayer is an interface name, not an expression.

Comment: u r very right i totally agree with what you are saying. my problem is view controller which has layer of images is loaded by playpauseaction method file so that is why i m confused how to define CALayer *myLayer = [CALayer layer]; // Create a CALayer object named myLayer

/*** code handling your layer ****/

[self pauseLayer:myLayer]; // Pause the CALayer myLayer

Comment: If you have defined your UIImageView in a separate file, you need to make that imageView accessible in the above class. Once you have it you can type something like [self pauseLayer:imageView.layer]

Comment: then i get message "use of undeclared identifier ImageView did you mean UIImageView".

Comment: That file is accessible in this class then why getting this message

Comment: it is not enough to import the file, you need to have a reference to that UIImageView. Create a method in your other class to get the UIImageView from there.

Comment: I updated the answer with an example. But I think that now this issue is about a complete different question. Please read about classes and objects in the Objective C programming guide.
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html

Comment: Thanks so much. Appreciate your time and help. In clearing the concept. Thanks again for helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

you need to put an instant not a class when you can your methods ..

so instead of calling it like this

```
[self PauseLayer:CALayer];
```

do something like

```
[self PauseLayer:(UIButton*)sender.layer];
```

Comment: It is not button. I am trying to pause and resume image view animation. For that i m using pause layer and resume layer

Comment: oh!! i did not see that ,, but I wanted to deliver some point!!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the P on 
-(void)pauseLayer:(CALayer*)layer {

to uppercase or the way around.